# awk: add two columns to csv that are the multiplication of a constant by the last column

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv-simple

I am trying to add two new columns to a csv file, that contain the multiplication of the last column to a constant. This last column is formed by the pound symbol and followed by a number.

Input:

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96
```

Expected Output:

```
id,tester,company,chief,previous_test,test,date,result,cost,euro,dollar
6582983b-61d4-4371-912d-bbc76bb8208b,Audrey Feest,Pagac-Gorczany,Claudine Moakson,18/02/2019,Passwords,20/05/2020,none,¬£11897.96,13682.65€,$16538.16
```

What I've done so far is take a substring of this column and create another two with it, but all I get is two copies of the last column without the pound symbol:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," 'NR==1 { print $0,"euro,dollar"; next }
{ w = substr($9, 2);
  u = substr($9, 2);
  print $0, w, u }' file.csv
```

All I have to do now is multiply those 2 columns by a constant each (1.15 and 1.39 respectively) and add the symbols to each column (€ and $), but I get stuck using the `print` command at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=","; CONVFMT="%.2f" }
          { $(NF+1)=(NR>1?    substr($9,3)*1.15"€":"euro")
            $(NF+1)=(NR>1? "$"substr($9,3)*1.39   :"dollar")
}1' infile
```

Read [what is the use of `CONVFMT`?](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strings-And-Numbers)

Comment: I get an error `awk: cmd. line:1: ^syntax error` pointing to `=NR>1`.

Comment: @LlemColop a common problem with unparenthesized ternary expressions is they produce syntax errors in some awks in some contexts. Change each `=NR>1 ? foo : bar` to `=(NR>1 ? foo : bar)`. Rule of thumb - always parenthesize your ternary expressions because that always makes the code clearer as well as more portable and then you don't have to think about which situations actually require the parens.